# Segmentation fault copying tree nodes into array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault, binary-tree

I use this structure for my tree:

```
  typedef struct product{
      char name[50];
      char id[5];
      double price;
      int amount;
      struct product *left_p, *right_p;
  }product_t;
```

So, I must convert the tree into an array.
I wrote this for the tree dimension:

```
int tree_dim(product_t *node_p){
    int i = 1 ;
    if (node_p == NULL)
        i = 0;
    else{
        i += tree_dim(node_p->left_p);
        i += tree_dim(node_p->right_p);
    }
    return i;
}
```

My tree is populated by reading the records from a txt file. The records are 21 and the value returned by tree_dim is correct. The value is stored in`arr_dim`.

Then I create a`product_t *products_a;` which will be the "array" and allocate it in memory by using `products_a = malloc (arr_dim*sizeof (product_t));`

Now, this is the function to fill the array with the tree nodes:

```
void fill_array(int *index, product_t *node_p, product_t *products_a){

    if (node_p != NULL){
        fill_array(index, node_p->left_p, products_a);
        products_a[*index++] = *node_p;
        fill_array(index, node_p->right_p, products_a);
    
    }
}
```

But it gives me segmentation fault error so I also tried this 2nd solution:

```
int fill_array(product_t *node_p, product_t *products_a){

    int i = 1 ;
    if (node_p == NULL){
        i=0;
    }
    else
    {
        i += fill_array(node_p->left_p, products_a);
        products_a[i-1] = *node_p;
        i += fill_array(node_p->right_p, products_a);
    
    }
    return i;
 }
```

Which doesn't give segmentation fault but when I print the array there are empty positions.
I need some tips on where I'm wrong. Maybe a problem with the index and the recursive calls but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Using a debugger looks to be the best way to understant your issue. A test on overfoll for `products_a` is missing.

Comment: I think `*index++` doesn't do what you expect.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) of these two operators

```
*index++
```

`++` Incrementation has higher precedence than `*` dereference right?

So if you first move in memory by `sizeof(int)` then you arent no more in your allocated memory and dereferencing would cause UB.

Its always better to use brackets `()` if you arent sure about precedence.

```
(*index)++ // This is right
```

Answer (score 0):

Filip has already pointed out the problem with your first function.

The problem with your second function is that it works only when filling from the left branch. After you have done that and copied the current product, there are some elements in the array, but copying from the right branch will start at index 0 again, so it will overwrite existing data and leave data at the end uninitialised.

You could fix this by passing the current index `i` to your function, but I find the `i = func(..., i);` syntax a bit redundant.

In C, you can pass in a subarray of `array` starting at element `i` with `&array[i]` or just `array + i`. (Remember that an array in a function call "decays" into a pointer to the first element, `&array[0]`.)

So this will work:

```
int fill_array(product_t *node_p, product_t *products_a)
{        
    int i = 0;

    if (node_p == NULL) return 0;

    i += fill_array(node_p->left_p, products_a);
    products_a[i++] = *node_p;
    i += fill_array(node_p->right_p, &products_a[i]);

    return i;
}
```